# Maximum update depth exceeded using react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep on getting this error in my react app. 
*Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

here's a sample code

I'm trying to use a react-select component. but I have to parse my data into an array having 2 objects(as required by the component). value & label. 
But i keep getting this error

```
let options = []

const { selectedOption } = this.state;

this.state.optionValue.map((value, i) =>  {
    return(
        options.push(
            this.setState({
                value: value.name,
                label: value.desc
            })
        )
    );
})
```

Comment: code makes no sense.... why are you pushing what this.setState returns into an array?

Comment: everything from optionValue will be stored in options. so I can assign it to the props of the react-select component. The optionValue array has no object "value" and "label". So i created an empty "options" array where I will then store 2 objects(value and label) inside assigning to them objects from the "optionValue" array.. I don't know if you understand what i'm explaining.. but if you do. Can you propose a better solution?

Comment: no clue what that means. There is zero reason to use setState if you trying to update options array.

Comment: So how do I enter objects from one array into another empty array using objects from the first array as inputs in react?

Comment: setState has nothing to do with what you are attempting to do.... `options.push({
                value: value.name,
                label: value.desc
            })` in reality you are using map()  which is wrong if you are using push(). You should just be returning the object.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks alot... That was the issue